# Terminal copy paste is not working when en keyboard is on

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, terminator

I just upgraded to 16 LTS. I have 2 keyboard layout used, Hungarian and English (US). When i use the `hu` keyboard layout, ctrl+shift+c and v works perfectly in every terminal (i usually use terminator) but when i switch to `en` it stops working. If i press it (ctrl+shift+v) twice i get a "letter" that look like this: `^V`

I google a lot, and all i found was to search for overriding keyboard shortcuts, but i haven't found any (not in terminator, not in system settings) and the funny part is that it only occurs when i use `en` layout

EDIT

Output of the requested command:

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwertz)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+hu+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(swapescape)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Comment: Interesting, I use the same two layouts (more precisely "English (US)" and "Hungarian (101/qwerty/dot/dead keys)") and have never experienced anything like this. ^V appearing after pressing it twice means that the Shift gets lost, Ctrl+V is meant to do this when pressed twice. What is your desktop environment? How did you configure these layouts, via graphical settings or manually via command line? Could you please share the output of "setxkbmap -print" with both layouts being active? Also please try all combinations of left/right shift and left/right ctrl, what's the result in each layout?...

Comment: ... What's your hotkey (if any) for switching between layouts? I can imagine the hotkey of Ctrl+Shift causing troubles for example.

Comment: I use Mate, and configured it via the graphical interface, i ll post the output tomorrow morning

Comment: Okay I _guess_ we'll have something substantially different then. I use Unity / GNOME3 which loads only one keymap at a time to X's xkb subsystem and grabs the toggle hotkey itself and loads the other keymap when it catches the hotkey getting pressed. Mate / GNOME2, as far as I recall, loads both keymaps into X's xkb subsystem at once, and lets X / xkb do the toggle.

Comment: @egmont I edited the post with the requested output. I dont see a shortcut for switching between layouts in the keyboard shortcut graphical UI